# Having problems with associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a restaurant app that will list restaurants as a rails starting project. For now, I want the restaurant to have one menu.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :menu
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

I've also added a migration for `restaurant_id` on the menu by running `rails generate migration AddRestaurantIDToMenus restaurant_id:integer` and ran `rake db:migrate`

My problem now is how do I associate a new menu to a restaurant? When I create a new menu post it does not automatically associate with a restaurant. Is there anyway I can create a menu directly from the restaurant's show page? What would I need to set up in the restaurant controller area for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you do a migration of a model that belongs to another model, don't add the foreign key manually, instead use `references` for the column type, like this

```
rails g migration AddRestaurantRefToMenus restaurant:references
```

Now, when you want to create a menu that belongs to an instance of Restaurant, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
@menu = @restaurant.menus.create(some_attribute: some_value, another_attibute: another_value)
```

Definitely read through [the rails guides on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... You have so much to learn...

First of all – it sounds like you're still in the early stages of your app, so unless you have a strong reason to keep any data that's already in your database, there's no real reason to create a whole new migration just to add the `restaurant_id` to your `Menu` table. Just `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`, edit your `create_menus` migration, and then `rake db:migrate' up again.

As far as actually creating a menu and associating it with a restaurant, you can do it any number of ways:

Restaurant or Menu controller:

```
def create_menu
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[id])
  @menu  = Menu.create(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id, :other_attribute => "something")

  #Or...
  @restaurant.menu = Menu.create(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id, :other_attribute => "something")

  #Or...
  @menu  = Menu.new(:other_attribute => "something")
  if @menu.save #returns true if saved properly
    @restaurant.menus << @menu
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to how to do both together, you could say in your Restaurants model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu
```

Then in the new of your controller you would have something like

```
@restaurant  = Restaurant.new
@restaurant.menu = Menu.new
```

Your new view would now look something like

```
form_for (@restaurant) do |r|
  <%= r... %> #whatever they can set for the restaurant (like a name maybe)
  #

  r.fields_for :menu do |m|
    <%= m... %> #whatever they can set for the menu 
  end

  r.submit "button"
end
```

Lastly create in your controller would look something like

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.new(params[:restaurant])
if (@restaurant.save)
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

You can do this with edit/update almost the exact same way (the main difference there being that your restaurant, and perhaps its menu, already exist) so your edit would look something like

```
@restaurant.find(params[:id])
```

then in your update it would look like

```
@restaurant.find(params[:id])
if @restaurant.update_attributes(params[:id])
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Hope that helps answer some questions you have.

p.s. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) is a good place to start if you have questions about form_for and the different inputs.